Notification module ASP.NET Web API
I'm developping a notification module, my project is an ASP.NET Web API with react. I want to ask what I need to interact between React and the API.
Example: if a user logs in, then sever will send a notification to welcome the user. If I use a webhook, I need to create a payload in LoginService, but it is very inconvenient if the project has a lot modules, please suggest a solution
